# Reflection property in traces of $SU(N)$ generators

Tags: group-theory, scattering, lie-algebra, spinors

Pure gluon amplitudes could be organized on different basis, most common ones are the trace basis and the DDM (Del Duca-Dixon-Maltoni) basis, see [DDM's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9910563), for better comprehension and to see how both are connected.

Let us focus on the first basis

$$
\mathcal{A}_n^{\text{tree}}(1,2,\ldots,n)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n-1}}Tr(T^{a_1}T^{a_{\sigma_2}}\ldots T^{a_{\sigma_n}})A_n(1,\sigma(2),\ldots,\sigma(n))
$$

Where $S_{n-1}$ stands for the set of all the permutations of $n-1$ objects.

Note also that $\mathcal{A}_n$ represents the whole amplitude, $A_n$ a partial amplitude, and color factors are taken into consideration in the trace terms.

It is a fact that every partial amplitude obeys

$$
A_n(1,2,\ldots,n)=(-1)^nA_n(n,\ldots,2,1)
$$

among other properties, see for example the following reviews [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.13012),[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697)

And this could be proven for example by inverting the ordering of any partial amplitude. And as it is mentioned in [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9910563), this reflection property is inherited from the traces in the color decomposition, described in the first equation, i.e.

$$
Tr(T^{a_1}T^{a_2}\ldots T^{a_n})=(-1)^nTr(T^{a_n}\ldots T^{a_2}T^{a_1})
$$

How can I prove the last?
My attempt so far is something like the following

$$
Tr(T^{a_1}T^{a_2}\ldots T^{a_n})^*=Tr((T^{a_1}T^{a_2}\ldots T^{a_n})^\dagger)\\
=Tr({T^{a_n}}^\dagger\ldots{T^{a_2}}^\dagger{T^{a_1}}^\dagger)\\
=Tr(T^{a_n}\ldots T^{a_2}T^{a_1})
$$

where I have used $T^\dagger=T$. Inspired by the above, I have tried to consider

$$
Tr((T^{a_1}T^{a_2}\ldots T^{a_n})^T)=Tr({T^{a_n}}^t\ldots{T^{a_n}}^t{T^{a_n}}^t)\\
=Tr({T^{a_n}}^*\ldots{T^{a_n}}^*{T^{a_n}}^*)
$$

where I have used $T^t={({(T^*)}^t)}^*={T^\dagger}^*=T^*$, which could lead to think that $T^*=-T$, however this is not generally true neither in $SU(2)$ nor $SU(3)$.

Any suggestion or recommended reading will be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you get that explicit formula for the $T^{a_i}$ ? Because if $T^a = \frac{1}{2}\lambda^a$ and $\lambda^a$ are the Gell-Mann-Matrices, one gets from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Lie_algebra_3] for n=3  instead $tr(ABC) = -tr(CBA) + \frac{1}{2}d_{ABC}$.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. I haven't seen that property as such anywhere until now, however, the third paragraph of exercise 2.30 of the following [Scattering amplitudes review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.1697.pdf) makes me think that the property seems to exist and in fact, it is the only way I can solve the said exercise.

Comment: "use the cyclic and reflection properties of the trace and the color-ordered amplitudes". I think from the structure of the sentence: cyclic -> trace and reflection -> colour-ordered amplitudes. I would rephrase the question, to focus on what you mainly want to prove, in order to provide context.